# Prove that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $(G/K)/(N/K).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

> Let $\varphi$ be a homomorphism of $G$ onto $G$ with ${\rm Ker} K$. Suppose $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $N = \{x \in G | \varphi(x)\in N\}$.

Need to prove that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $(G/K)/(N/K)$.

This is what I have for now:

For $a, b\in G$,
$$\sigma\varphi(ab) = \sigma(\varphi(ab)) = \sigma(\varphi(a)\varphi(b)) = \sigma(\varphi(a))\sigma(\varphi(b)) = \sigma\varphi(a)\sigma\varphi(b).$$

So $\sigma\varphi$ is a homomorphism.

If $a\in \text{Ker} \varphi$, then $\sigma\varphi(a) = \sigma(eH) = eK$ where $eH$ (resp. eK) is the identity of H
(resp. $K$).

Therefore $a\in \text{Ker} \sigma\phi$. This implies that $\text{Ker} \phi \leqslant \text{Ker} \sigma\phi$. Furthermore, $\text{Ker} \phi / \text{Ker} \sigma\phi$.

Indeed, $\text{Ker} \phi / G$ so $\forall g\in \text{Ker} \sigma\phi\leqslant G, g \text{Ker} \sigma g−1 \subset \text{Ker} \phi.$

Moreover, if $\varphi$ and $\sigma$ are onto and $G$ is finite, then from the first isomorphism theorem,

$$|G| = | \text{Ker} \varphi||\varphi(G)| = | \text{Ker} \varphi||H|$$

and

$$|G| = | \text{Ker} \sigma\varphi||\sigma\varphi(G)| = | \text{Ker} \sigma\varphi||K|.$$

So
$$ [\text{Ker} \sigma \varphi : \text{Ker} \varphi] = | \text{Ker} \sigma \varphi| /| \text{Ker} \varphi| = |G|/|K|/|G|/|H| = |H|/|K|.$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I fixed your tex, but I'm not sure what you mean on the entire line starting with "Indeed"

Comment: You cannnot say that the index equals $|\ker(\sigma\varphi)|/|\ker(\varphi)|$ unless you are assuming your groups are finite, and there is no need to assume the groups are finite. So I would certainly object to your assertions at the end.

Comment: Hint for a proof: Define a map $G/K\to G/N$ that is surjective with kernel $N/K$.